# Bagging Classifier on the RCV1 dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, ensemble-learning

I have to implement a bagging classifier on the RCV1 dataset. I am using Python in Google Colab.

I separated the dataset as explained in the documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/real_world.html#rcv1-dataset) : 23149 samples in my training set and the rest in my testing set.

My goal is to find if a sample is matching a specific categorie. For that, I only took the first column of the target as my label vector. Here is the code I used to separate the dataset :

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_rcv1
rcv1 = fetch_rcv1()
y = rcv1.target.toarray()[:, 0]

X_train = rcv1.data[0:23149]
X_test = rcv1.data[23149:]
y_train = y[0:23149]
y_test = y[23149:]
```

Firstly, I tried to run a single DecisionTreeClassifier on it and calculate the accuracy, the precision, the recall and the f1 score for both my training set and my testing set :

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_predict = dt.predict(X_train)
print("Accuracy : ", accuracy_score(y_train, y_predict))
print(confusion_matrix(y_train, y_predict))
print("Precision : ", precision_score(y_train, y_predict))
print("Recall : ", recall_score(y_train, y_predict))
print("F1 Score : ", f1_score(y_train, y_predict))

y_predict = dt.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy : ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predict))
print("Precision : ", precision_score(y_test, y_predict))
print("Recall : ", recall_score(y_test, y_predict)) 
print("F1 Score : ", f1_score(y_test, y_predict))
```

I got these results :

```
Accuracy :  0.999049634973433
[[22475     0]
 [   22   652]]
Precision :  1.0
Recall :  0.9673590504451038
F1 Score :  0.9834087481146305


Accuracy :  0.9536341702239317
[[739253  18361]
 [ 17863   5788]]
Precision :  0.23967866164230403
Recall :  0.24472538159063043
F1 Score :  0.24217573221757324
```

From what I understood, as this model have a high variance, the utilisation of bagging should help to reduce it and find a better model.

So, I tried to use a BaggingClassifier and find the best parameters with a GridSearchCV :

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

baggingDT = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier())
param_grid = [
    {'n_estimators' : [2, 5, 10], 'max_samples': [0.33, 0.66, 1.0]},             
]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(baggingDT, param_grid, cv=3, scoring='f1')
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(grid_search.best_params_)
```

The best parameters found were n_estimators = 5 and max_samples = 0.66. So i made the same calculations than before with my new model :

```
baggingDT = grid_search.best_estimator_
y_predict = baggingDT.predict(X_train)
print("Accuracy : ", accuracy_score(y_train, y_predict))
print(confusion_matrix(y_train, y_predict))
print("Precision : ", precision_score(y_train, y_predict))
print("Recall : ", recall_score(y_train, y_predict))
print("F1 Score : ", f1_score(y_train, y_predict))

y_predict = baggingDT.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy : ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predict))
print("Precision : ", precision_score(y_test, y_predict))
print("Recall : ", recall_score(y_test, y_predict)) 
print("F1 Score : ", f1_score(y_test, y_predict))
```

Here are the results I got :

```
Accuracy :  0.9882500323988077
[[22453    22]
 [  250   424]]
Precision :  0.9506726457399103
Recall :  0.629080118694362
F1 Score :  0.757142857142857


Accuracy :  0.9689810755633492
[[753648   3966]
 [ 20268   3383]]
Precision :  0.4603347394203293
Recall :  0.14303834932983805
F1 Score :  0.21825806451612903
```

These results don't seem to be satisfying for me because, althought the precision has augmented a little, the recall has decreased and the number of true positives found is less than before.

Am I missing something or is there a reason that the bagging classifier doesn't work as intended?

Comment: "*I only took the first column of the target as my label vector*" is quite vague and unclear; in order to make this a [mcve], please include the code for preparing your `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_val`, and `y_val`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added it as well as the code I used to do the calculations with my bagging model.

Comment: It's not like the RCV1 labels are very well-defined or consistently annotated; they are the result of humans in a deadline-driven environment picking from a long list of obscure options. Perhaps see the critique of the corpus published by Lewis et al, with related resources at http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/jmlr/papers/volume5/lewis04a/lyrl2004_rcv1v2_README.htm

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, it helped me to better understand the dataset and the results that i got with the decision tree alone. What I still don't understand is why the use of bagging gives me a recall lower than the use of a single decision tree.

Comment: Vaguely useless to wonder why one garbage in/garbage out result is worse than another, don't you think? Try manually vetting a few of the categories, and train and test on that.

Comment: @tripleee Ok thanks, I will try that.